# How to forbid undecorated classes to be passed in as parameter?

Tags: typescript, decorator

In TypeScript, I defined a decorator

```
function Foo(type: AnEnum) {
    return <T extends { pattern: RegExp, new(...args: any[]): {} }>(constructor: T) => {
        RegisterPattern(pattern) // defined elsewhere
        return class extends constructor {
            public type: AnEnum = type
        }
    }
}
```

and use it as

```
@Token(AnEnum.Bar)
class Bar {
    public static pattern = /./
    public test: number
    constructor() {
        this.test = 1
    }
}
```

I hope that only classes decorated with `@Foo` are passed into a function like

```
function func(decoratedObject: DecoratedType) {
    /* something */
}
```

and TypeScript should recognize that an additional field called `type` is added. Is it possible? Or is it a bad design pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript does not currently support modeling type mutation via decorators.

This feature has been requested and is discussed extensively in  [TypeScript/issues/4881](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881)

To get the desired effect, you must call the decorator as function and capture the resulting value.

For a decorator, that means writing:

```
const decorated = decorator(class {});
```

for a decorator factory, that means writing:

```
const decorated = decorator(configuration)(class {});
```

Comment: So is it something related to the github issue https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881?

Comment: @obfish yes. Exactly. Thanks for linking the correct tracking issue.